# How do I run a service as a non-root user at boot, without entering a password?

Tags: sudo, systemd

I have a process that I want to start when the host boots. I want that process to run as a non-root user. And I won't necessarily be around to enter a password on the tty when it starts. Here's my `systemd` service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nethermind Node
Documentation=https://docs.nethermind.io
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nethermind
Group=nethermind
EnvironmentFile=/data/nethermind/.env
WorkingDirectory=/data/nethermind
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nethermind --datadir /data/nethermind
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=1000000

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The `nethermind` user exists, is a member of the sudoers group, and has a password at present. I've also tested this when the user has no password.

What I get when I start the service (running `service` as root), is this:

```
$ sudo service nethermind start
$ journalctl -u nethermind -f
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake sudo[1725]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake nethermind[1725]: sudo: a password is required
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake sudo[1725]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [nethermind]
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: nethermind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: nethermind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: nethermind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: Stopped Nethermind Node.
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: nethermind.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: nethermind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 03:20:45 stake systemd[1]: Failed to start Nethermind Node.
```

Does this mean the executable is trying to sudo itself? It makes sense to me that it I'd need to enter a password for the `nethermind` user in that case, but I want this to run non-interactively.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Based on this, whatever `/usr/bin/nethermind` is it is attempting to `sudo` and gain superuser privileges.  This is where you might need to run this as `root` instead of user level replacing `user` and `group` with `root`.  however, this is **dangerous** so you need to understand that this will cause a large security concern.  If the process needs superuser privileges to call `sudo` or such, then this is a program that I would be sandboxing in a container (a system container like an LXD container), not giving root access to the main system.

Comment: Agreed, I don't want to run this as root. I'd like to avoid the complexity of containerisation. Could be I need to go back to the process itself and figure out why it's trying to `sudo` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/NethermindEth/nethermind/issues/4703) in Nethermind. `usr/bin/nethermind` is actually just [a wrapper](https://github.com/NethermindEth/nethermind/blob/cb0863c2a25ecbe8e8d80dbcc851acc03e2ed5f6/scripts/execution.sh), and the wrapper tries to sudo.

To bypass the problem, just run the "real" Nethermind executable directly:

```
/usr/share/nethermind/Nethermind.Runner --datadir ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `/sbin/runuser` command in your service file. I use it for ssh tunnel. So it would be like this.

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l nethermind -c "/usr/bin/nethermind --datadir /data/nethermind"
```

Then you can edit `/etc/sudoers` file to have `nethermind` user run `nethermind` command without a password.

```
nethermind ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nethermind
```

You might have to have `/usr/bin/sudo` in the `ExecStart` line of service file then.

Comment: I made the change to `etc/sudoers` and then tested this use of `runuser` directly, not as part of the systemd service yet. A password was still required. I got: `# /sbin/runuser -l nethermind -c "/usr/bin/nethermind --datadir /data/nethermind"
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required`

Comment: That is likely because you didnt add sudo to service file. Id try 'ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l nethermind -c "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nethermind --datadir /data/nethermind"' in your service file if you want. Other than that I dont have anymore suggestions. Notice I added sudo before nethermind command.